# Type MailMessage is not defined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to get a simple mail script up and running in .NET. The problem is that I keep getting the error message `Type MailMessage is not defined`, but I have imported `System.Net.Mail` in the CodeFile. Below is my Default.aspx.vb.

If I declare it like `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail"%>` at the top of the file and don't use a MasterPage and CodeFile it works, but then I can't use MasterPage.

I'm new at this. What am I missing?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Xml
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Me.IsPostBack = False Then

    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Beginning of my mail script looks like this:

```
<script runat="server">
    Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   


    Dim myMail As New MailMessage()
```

Comment: So I'm reading your question, and there's not a lot of separation between what works and what doesn't work. Are you complaining that the 'Imports' in the code behind is not having an effect on markup side?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to explain :) The only thing that is harder than solving the problem is trying to explain the problem. Please se my comment to below for info on how I solved it and what the problem is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are writing your code in aspx page

Add `Import` statement after page directive

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail"%>
```

Or

```
Dim myMail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
```

Comment: I used the second code example and it solved it. But now it says that the property To is ReadOnly in rhis line: myMail.To = "myaddress@domain.com". Any idea?

Comment: Found a work around by doing this: myMail.To.Add("myaddress@domain.com")

Comment: But maybe you can help me out with the from field. Why si this not working: myMail.From = "myaddress@domain.com"

Comment: @john use `myMail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(address)` Visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) for Constructors of the MailAddress class